# Using Spring Boot @MockBean annotation in RabbitMQ Listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a base class for integration tests which is setting up a Testcontainer for RabbitMQ. I'm inheriting in every Integration Test from this particular class and it works really well for me.

However, I do have a test which requires a mock instance as a bean. When the test runs alone everything works well, but if any integration test runs before this test, a mocked bean is not injected into the RabbitMQ Listener instance bean but the implementation is used.
Which options do I have to register a mocked instance in the application context?

I have tried so far:

- `@DirtiesContext`

  - only on the test class doesn't work
  - on both test classes works
- `@TestConfiguration` with `@Primary` Bean

The code is also available on GitHub: https://github.com/twobiers/mockbean-rabbitmq
This is my RabbitMQListener which makes use of a bean:

```java
@Component
public class MessageConsumer {
  private final BeanToConsume bean;

  public MessageConsumer(BeanToConsume bean) {
    this.bean = bean;
  }

  @RabbitListener(bindings = {
      @QueueBinding(
          value = @Queue(value = "test", durable = "true"),
          exchange = @Exchange(value = "amq.fanout", type = "fanout")
      )
  })
  public void getBean() {
    System.out.println("BeanToConsume is of type: " + bean.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

My Base class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class AbstractIntegrationTest {

  static RabbitMQContainer rabbitMQ = new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:3.9.5-alpine");

  static {
    rabbitMQ.start();
  }

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void setRabbitMQ(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.host", () -> "localhost");
    registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.port", () -> rabbitMQ.getAmqpPort());
    registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.username", () -> rabbitMQ.getAdminUsername());
    registry.add("spring.rabbitmq.password", () -> rabbitMQ.getAdminPassword());
  }
}
```

And both test classes

```java
// This runs first
class FirstIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  @Test
  void test() {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("amq.fanout", "", "test");
  }
}

// Afterwards this
class SecondIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
  @MockBean
  BeanToConsume beanToConsume;

  @Autowired
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  @Test
  void test() {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("amq.fanout", "", "test");
  }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, do the tests in `FirstIntegrationTest` make use of classes that would have `RabbitMqService` injected? Just trying to figure out if it's fine to just use a mocked bean throughout or if you actually need the real instance in some scenarios.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying if `FirstIntegrationTest` runs before `SecondIntegrationTest`, the mock bean is replaced by the actual, whereas if `SecondIntegrationTest` runs first, you get the mock bean as expected? If so, create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because the code you’ve shown has nothing to trigger this behavior.

Comment: @SteveE no, neither the tests or the tested code of `FirstIntegrationTest` makes use of that particular class. A global mock would probably work, but at the moment I'm trying to understand what is triggering the behaviour.
@AbhijitSarkar Yes, exactly. I thought I was missing something obvious, I will try to reproduce it. Actually my first attempt couldn't trigger that either. Will edit the question on further evidence.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You were right the shown code couldn't state the problem. My real problem is that the Mocked instance is not injected into the RabbitListenerContainer. I have updated the question and provided a repository with a reproducible example. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same `RabbitTemplate` bean in two tests, and in one of the test classes, you inject a seemingly unrelated mock bean and expect the `RabbitTemplate` to be reinitialized. That’s not how it works, because Spring beans are singleton scoped by default, and since the `RabbitTemplate` is already created in `FirstIntegrationTest` without a mocked dependency, the same instance in injected again into `SecondIntegrationTest`.

I didn’t try to run your GitHub code, but can offer two choices off the top of my head.

1. Create the mock bean in the abstract superclass. If you never need the real bean, this is the simplest option.
2. Create the `RabbitTemplate` with prototype scope in `SecondIntegrationTest`. This will allow for the bean to be mocked only in this class, while other tests can use the real one.

Comment: I don't expect anything on the `RabbitTemplate` beans, those are just used to send messages. My expectation is that during the execution of `SecondIntegrationTest` the bean `BeanToConsume` is being swapped out with a mocked instance in the application context. In fact this is happening, but the change is not reflected into the MessageListenerContainer (The RabbitListener). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html. I guess because it is on a different thread or so.